# Find text using lxml etree

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to get a text from one tag using `lxml etree`.

```
<div class="litem__type">
            <div>
                Robbp
            </div>


                    <div>Estimation</div>

                 +487 (0)639 14485653


                                •
                                <a href="mailto:herbrich@gmail.com">
                                    Email Address
                                </a>



                    •
                    <a class="external" href="http://www.google.com">
                        Homepage
                    </a>


        </div>
```

The problem is that I can't locate it because there are many differences between this kind of snippets. There are situations, when the first and second `div` is not there at all. As you can see, the telephone number is not in it's own `div`.

I suppose that it would be possible to extract the telephone using `BeautifulSoups` contents but I'm trying to use `lxml` module's `xpath`.

Do you have any ideas? (email don't have to be there sometimes)

EDIT: The best idea is probably to use `regex` but I don't know how to tell it that it should extract just text between two `<div></div>`

Comment: Is the telephone number always immediately before the `<a>` tag containing the email address? Is the format of the telephone number always the same? (If it varies, it would help to give a description of how it varies, including examples showing all the variations.) Is there some other pattern or rule that can be used to identify the telephone number?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using regex to parse XML/HTML wherever possible because it is not as efficient as using element trees.

The text after element A's closing tag, but before element B's opening tag, is called element A's `tail` text. To select this `tail` text using `lxml etree` you could do the following:

```
content = '''
<div class="litem__type">
    <div>Robbp</div>
    <div>Estimation</div>
    +487 (0)639 14485653
    <a href="mailto:herbrich@gmail.com">Email Address</a>
    <a class="external" href="http://www.google.com">Homepage</a>
</div>'''

from lxml import etree

tree = etree.XML(content)
phone_number = tree.xpath('div[2]')[0].tail.strip()
print(phone_number)
```

**Output**

```
'+487 (0)639 14485653'
```

The `strip()` function is used here to remove whitespace on either side of the `tail` text.

Comment: Thanks but I think this will not work because as I've written, the first or second div don't have to exists there. The same with email.

Comment: If the first and second div aren't there, use the same code as I've suggested, but with `phone_number = tree.xpath('text()')[0].strip()`

Comment: @gtlambert The `tree.xpath('text()')` will get you list of all the text `['\n    ', '\n    ', '\n    +487 (0)639 14485653\n    ', '\n    ', '\n']` and as you can see the first element [0] is just a newline with spaces.  So the suggestion should have a join then strip such as `"".join(tree.xpath("text()")).strip()`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and get text after div tag.

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("filename.xml")
items = tree.xpath('//div')
for node in items:
    # you can check here if it is a phone number
    print node.tail
```